# Scrapy infinite scrolling - no pagination indication

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to web scraping and I encountered some issues when I was trying to scrape a website with infinite scroll. I looked at some other questions but I could not find the answer, so I hope someone could help me out here.

I am working on the website http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/analysis/stock-aafn/00001/0/all/. I have the following (very basic) piece of code some far, where I could get every piece of article on the first page (20 entries).

```
    def parse(self, response):

        # collect all article links
        news = response.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class,'newshead4')]//a//text()").extract()  
        # visit each news link and gather news info
        for n in news:
            url = urljoin(response.url, n)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_news)
```

However, I could not figure out how to go to the next page. I read some tutorials online, such as going to Inspect -> Network and observe the Request URL after scrolling, it returned `http://www.aastocks.com/tc/resources/datafeed/getmorenews.ashx?cat=all&newstime=905169272&newsid=NOW.895783&period=0&key=&symbol=00001` where I could not find an indication of pagination or other pattern to help me go to the next page. When I copy this link to a new tab, I see a json document with the news of the next page, but without a url with it. In this case, how could I fix it? Many thanks!

Comment: urls to news are similar to `http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/analysis/stock-aafn-con/00001/NOW.964845/all` and you can create new links using data from JSON. ie. use `NOW.895758` in place of `NOW.964845`

Comment: Hi @furas, thanks for the reply. However, would you be able to elaborate a bit more? I get the part of replacing the `NOW.XXXXXX`, but I still don't get how can I automatically go to the next page so that I could retrieve the `NOW.XXXXXX`.

Comment: scroll page few times to get your url (`getmorenews.ashx`) few times and you will see that they have different parameterts. So to get data from next page you have to use this url with different parameters. And now compare parameters in url for next page with data which you get in previous data. You should find them. So JSON has not only information to create links to articles but also information to create link for JSON data from next page.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score -1):

Link

http://www.aastocks.com/tc/resources/datafeed/getmorenews.ashx?cat=all&newstime=905169272&newsid=NOW.895783&period=0&key=&symbol=00001

gives JSON data with values like `NOW.XXXXXX` which you can use to generate links to news

```
"http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/analysis/stock-aafn-con/00001/" + "NOW.XXXXXX" + "/all"
```

If you scroll down few times then you will see that next pages generate similar links but with different parameters `newstime`, `newsid`.

If you check JSON data then you will see that last item has values `'dtd'` and `'id'` which are the same as parameters `newstime`, `newsid` in link used to download JSON data for next page.

So you can generate link to get JSON data for next page(s).

```
"http://www.aastocks.com/tc/resources/datafeed/getmorenews.ashx?cat=all&newstime=" + DTD + "&newsid=" + ID + "&period=0&key=&symbol=00001"
```

---

Working example with `requests`

```
import requests

newstime = '934735827'
newsid = 'HKEX-EPS-20190815-003587368'

url = 'http://www.aastocks.com/tc/resources/datafeed/getmorenews.ashx?cat=all&newstime={}&newsid={}&period=0&key=&symbol=00001'
url_article = "http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/analysis/stock-aafn-con/00001/{}/all"

for x in range(5):

    print('---', x, '----')
    print('data:', url.format(newstime, newsid))

    # get JSON data
    r = requests.get(url.format(newstime, newsid))
    data = r.json()

    #for item in data[:3]: # test only few links
    for item in data[:-1]: # skip last link which gets next page

        # test links to articles
        r = requests.get(url_article.format(item['id']))
        print('news:', r.status_code, url_article.format(item['id']))

    # get data for next page
    newstime = data[-1]['dtd']
    newsid = data[-1]['id']
    print('next page:', newstime, newsid)
```